# DropDown Input using values from PHP json and implemented using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, input, dropdown

Im trying to modify an input drop down example, to use values I am pulling from a db. 
Here is my code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var dropoffsuburbcode2 = [];
    getEBRates();
function getEBRates()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();} 
        else {xmlhttp3 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}

xmlhttp3.onreadystatechange = function() 
{
        if (xmlhttp3.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp3.status == 200) 
{
            dropoffsuburbcode = xmlhttp3.responseText;
            setcode(dropoffsuburbcode);
}       
};
    xmlhttp3.open("GET","php/Rates.php",true);
    xmlhttp3.send();
}

function setcode(suburb){
dropoffsuburbcode2 = suburb;
dropoffsuburbcode2 = dropoffsuburbcode2.replace(/['"\]\[]/g, ''); 

alert(dropoffsuburbcode2);
```

This alert returns POCODE1SUBURB1,POCODE1SUBURB2

This code only works with availableTags, but when I try to use dropoffsuburbcode2 like i do below, I get nothing.

```
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL"    ];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: dropoffsuburbcode2
});
};
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

php file code below (Rates.php)

```
$strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM db_ebrates";
$EventList_rs2 = mysql_query($strSQL2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($EventList_rs2)) {
$ebsuburbarrray[] = "".$row['ebratesPostcode']. "" .$row['ebratesSuburb']. "";
}
echo json_encode($ebsuburbarrray);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because dropoffsuburbcode2 may not be an array of strings. But I would suggest you to use Ajax and populate the array from the json.